# Decimal part in C++;

Tags: c++

I'm looking for a function that returns the decimals part of a number(but not like 0.numbers), for example :

```
float x=12.3456;
```

I want it to return :

```
int i=3456;
```

I tried

```
x=x-(int)x;
i=x;
```

But it returns 0. ;

Comment: There is not always a clear number of decimal digits, because a floating point number is usually represented as (equivalent to) a fraction of integers a/b, where b is a power of 2. But you can do this by *specifying* the number of digits you want. E.g., for 5 digits, multiply the decimals part by 10 000, and convert to integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets take these two assignments one by one

```
x=x-(int)x;
i=x;
```

First you do `x=x-(int)x` which will result in `x` being equal to `0.346`. Then you do `i=x` which truncates (i.e. remove the decimals) of the value of `x` leading to `i` becoming zero.

You need to multiply `x` by `1000` before the assignment to `i`:

```
i = 1000 * x;
```

The number `1000` depends on the number of digits of decimals you want. More zeros means more digits.

Comment: So i must create a function that returns(an int e for example) the size of X ,
then multiply x with 10^e;

Answer (score 1):

To add to [Joachim Pileborg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35682443/3233921): if you really want to have *all* fractional digits in your integer, you could do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>

template <typename T>
long long fractional(T val)
{
  T frac = val - std::floor(val);
  long long alldigits(std::pow(10, std::numeric_limits<T>::digits10)*frac);
  while (alldigits%10 == 0)
  {
    alldigits /= 10;
  }
  return alldigits;
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << fractional<float>(1.0/8.0)  << std::endl; // 125
  std::cout << fractional<float>(1.0/3.0)  << std::endl; // 333333
  std::cout << fractional<double>(1.0/3.0) << std::endl; // 333333333333333
  return 0;
}
```

[Live example here.](http://ideone.com/Z7Hzbl)  But the example also shows the problems you'd run into: depending on the number and the precision of the underlying data type, you would get different amounts of digits, which ends up being difficult to interpret.  So most likely, getting a fixed number of digits is going to be the better solution.

Answer (score 1):

you could try this :

```
#include <iostream>


int intpart(float x) {
    float b = 0;
    x -= (int)x;
    while (x - (int)x != 0)
        x *= 10;
    return (int)x;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::cout << intpart(17.5) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```